# NVDA Screenreader - use Shortcuts to read out next item with current focus on textinputfield

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, wcag2.0, nvda

Just as the title says.
I cant find ANYTHING for this particular usecase Online.

This is in context of a website aiming to be AA WCAG 2.0 conform.

I have non-focussable text alongside focussable textinputs inside of a single view.
I can TAB through the focussable textinputs, but I cant read out the textfields inbetween. When I press "arrow down" while having the focus on the textinput I get "empty field" from NVDA. Most shortcuts also unfortunately produce text in the textinputfield instead of executing the associated behavior in NVDA.
Is there any way have the keystrokes being recognized as commands instead of input for the textfield? Is there any keyboard shortcut telling NVDA to behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, NVDA auto switches to Forms mode, so what you're getting is the correct behaviour. if that text is related to the field, then you should use aria-describedby="[id of text]", on the form element.

I wouldn't be looking at anything that changes the default behaviour of how it works, as this will undoubtedly cause issues, for end users.

Could you not put that text in a tooltip, that is only shown when a user tabs to an interactive icon, next to the input (using the aria-describedby attribute too)?